# using php is_dir('~/tmp') works on one machine, but not on another. Why?

Tags: php, apache, zend-server-ce

I am trying to run the following code:

```
is_dir('~/tmp');
```

On a shared LAMP stack. It works fine, and returns TRUE. (That directory exists.) When I run the same code on my local box (Mac OSX 10.5, running Zend Server Community Ed) I get FALSE which is wrong because ~/tmp exists and has permissions set to 777.

I am missing a server directive somewhere, I think.

I have checked with phpInfo and I have (on both local and production):

```
safe_mode           Off         Off

safe_mode_exec_dir  no value    no value

safe_mode_gid           Off         Off

safe_mode_include_dir   no value    no value

open_basedir    no value    no value
```

So I think that I am missing something, but what?

[edit...] Some more information...

running the following on my local

```
get_current_user()
```

gives me 'username', which is the correct user whose ~/tmp directory I want to verify, BUT

```
shell_exec('whoami')
```

gives me 'daemon'. So I think I know where my problem is coming from. Now I just need to figure out if/how I can change the user that is running the web server on my local.

Comment: You would use that directory to store temp files (read, use once then delete)?

Comment: Exactly. It's a place to put a debug log, for example.

Comment: You could use the `sys_get_temp_dir` function. I'll add a example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you expecting `~` to be expanded to your home directory? I would be reluctant to rely on that inside of PHP.  (Just tested it on my Mac, and it did not expand.)

If possible, try changing `~/tmp` to whatever the full path name is (e.g., something like `/Users/meriial/tmp`).

**UPDATE**:  Alternatively, you could replace `~` with `$_ENV['HOME']` as follows:

```
is_dir($_ENV['HOME'] . '/tmp');
```

Ideally, you'd check that `array_key_exists('HOME',$_ENV)` returns `TRUE` first and take some appropriate action (like use the system temp dir) if it doesn't.

For that matter, as @xmarcos points out, you could just use the system temp dir regardless using `sys_get_temp_dir()` and `tempnam()`.  That may be the most portable and therefore your best choice.  I think you can also do atomic temp file creation that way, so it may be  more secure and less prone to race conditions.

Comment: Yes, I am expecting ~ to expand into my home directory. It works on the shared hosting linux machine, but not on my mac. The challenge is that I would like to write to ~/tmp without having different code on the production and development machines.

Comment: Instead of using `~`, you could use the `$HOME` environment variable.

Comment: I should have been less confident that ~ was expanding to the home directory on my production server. (Because it wasn't.) Can we say with confidence that php _never_ expands ~ to the home directory?

Comment: I believe tilde expansion is a function of the shell and I see no documentation suggesting PHP replicates it. I wouldn't say with confidence that it never does it, but I strongly suspect that to be true.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that directory existes **inside** your user directory?

Go to `Terminal`, and type `cd ~/tmp`. Does is work?

**Update:** you could use the `sys_get_temp_dir` if available, code example:

```
$some_log = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'some_log');    
var_dump($some_log);
// will return '/private/var/folders/.../some_logbqzDvg'
```

Comment: +1 for `sys_get_temp_dir`. The issue is likely though that PHP runs as a different user, so `~` in PHP and `~` in the Terminal are two different directories.

Answer (score 2):

for all the virtual paths try to expand them first. do:

```
var_dump(realpath('~/tmp'));
```

and then see what happens,
and then try to `opendir()` it and see what error it gets.

Comment: ah ha! good advice. it turns out that on my production server, is_dir('~/tmp') was returning TRUE because the directory /path/to/working/directory/~/tmp existed, which I discovered after using realpath(). Because ~/tmp also existed, I had assumed that it was expanding ~ to the home directory, but it wasn't.

Comment: does this mean that php can/will never expand ~ to a home directory?

Comment: @meriial php has very little to do here. PHP workson the system and if system expands ~ so PHP does.

Comment: when you say 'system', do you mean shell? The shell on both my production (linux) and development (mac) servers expands ~, but php realpath() and is_dir() do not. See Trott's comment above.